# Simple Display Window program is giving error VS2012

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

```
#include<afxwin.h>
#include"stdafx.h"

class CSimpleFrame : public CFrameWnd
{
    public:
    CSimpleFrame()
    {
        Create(NULL,L"Windows Application");
    }       

};

struct CSimpleApp : public CWinApp
{
     BOOL InitInstance()
    {
        CSimpleFrame *Tester= new CSimpleFrame();
        m_pMainWnd=Tester;

        m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
        m_pMainWnd->UpdateWindow();

        return TRUE;
    }


};

CSimpleApp theApp;
```

This program is for displaying a simple window in vs2012.
Clearly i am new to windows programming.Also This error started coming after I created the global object theApp.

The error I am getting is the following.

```
    Debug Assertion Failed!
    Program: C:\Windows\system32\mfc110ud.dll
    File: f:\\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\appcore.cpp
    Line: 196

    **line 196 of appcore.cpp is**
    ASSERT(AfxGetThread() == NULL);
    When this error is shown i press retry.And then i press break and then continue then it gives another error
    Debug Assertion Failed!
    Program: C:\Windows\system32\mfc110ud.dll
    File: f:\\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\appcore.cpp
    Line: 203

    **line 203 of appcore.cpp is** 
    ASSERT(afxCurrentWinApp == NULL); // only one CWinApp object please
```

Comment: So... which one is line 182?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend MFC as a library of choice.

Comment: This code compiled and ran fine with VS2013.2 and VS2012.4. Have you installed update 4? I don't see an assertion at line 182 of appcore.cpp included in my VS2012 folder but that area of code is looking for a language resource DLL. What language OS are you using?

Comment: Also, how deep is your project folder because there is an assertion around there that the path is not too long.

Comment: i am installing update 4 now. but hav no idea about the other stuff u r talking about.

Comment: Have you tried stepping into the code in appcore at line 182 to determine what is causing the assert?

Comment: update 4 could not be installed because of some error midway

Answer (score 0):

I got same error and solved my problem this way. in case anybody faced  same problem you could use this solution.

These problem in MFC programming usually happens when project settings are not correctly set.
Go to project settings > Linker > System

In subsystem choose: (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)

This should do the trick.